# Vue Apollo TypeScript: ApolloClient is missing websocket properties

Tags: typescript, vue.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo, vue-testing-library

I'm trying to set up a component test with Vue Testing Library and Apollo as described in [their example](https://github.com/testing-library/vue-testing-library/blob/main/src/__tests__/vue-apollo.js).

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client'
import { render } from '@testing-library/vue'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4001/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    addTypename: false,
  }),
})

type ComponentType = Parameters<typeof render>[0]
const renderWithApollo = (Component: ComponentType) =>
  render(Component, undefined, (localVue) => {
    localVue.use(VueApollo)

    return {
      apolloProvider: new VueApollo({ defaultClient: apolloClient }),
    }
  })
```

However, when I do this, TypeScript yells about `defaultClient` with the following error:

```
Type 'ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>' is missing the following properties from type 'ApolloClient<any>': store, writeData, initQueryManager, wsClientts(2739)
apollo-provider.d.ts(16, 5): The expected type comes from property 'defaultClient' which is declared here on type '{ defaultClient: ApolloClient<any>; defaultOptions?: VueApolloComponentOptions<Vue> | undefined; clients?: { [key: string]: ApolloClient<any>; } | undefined; watchLoading?: WatchLoading | undefined; errorHandler?: ErrorHandler | undefined; prefetch?: boolean | undefined; }'
```

How can the ApolloClient miss those types and how do I give it those properties? It feels like I'm missing configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I was missing a `link` property and I had to call `provideApolloClient`:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client'
import { render } from '@testing-library/vue'
import fetch from 'cross-fetch'
import { provideApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4001',
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    addTypename: false,
  }),
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: '/graphql', fetch }),
})

type ComponentType = Parameters<typeof render>[0]
const renderWithApollo = (Component: ComponentType) =>
  render(Component, undefined, (localVue) => {
    localVue.use(VueApollo)

    provideApolloClient(apolloClient)

    return {
      // @ts-ignore
      apolloProvider: new VueApollo({ defaultClient: apolloClient }),
    }
  })
```